# how to correctly write conditions for * ngif

Tags: angular

there is some logic that is duplicated in the component template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let error of *object* | keyvalue">
    <p class="error-message">
      <span *ngIf="error.key === 'pattern'">{{...}}</span>
      <span *ngIf="error.key === 'maxlength'">{{...}}</span>
      <span *ngIf="error.key === 'required'">{{...}}</span>
    </p>
  </ng-container>
```

this is duplicated three times, except for `object` and `span`

I want to transfer all the logic to `ng-template`, something like this

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="errorMessage; context: *object* | keyvalue"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="errorMessage; context: *object2* | keyvalue"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="errorMessage; context: *object3* | keyvalue"></ng-container>

<ng-template #errorMessage let-error>
    <p class="error-message">
        <span *ngIf="error.key === 'pattern' && context === *object*">{{...}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="error.key === 'pattern' && context === *object2*">{{...}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="error.key === 'maxlength' && context === *object*">{{...}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="error.key === 'required' && context === *object*">{{...}}</span>
        ///
      </p>
</ng-template>
```

Is it possible to write a similar condition in `*ngIf`? or how to correctly write conditions for `*ngIf`?

Comment: @manjirosano Thanks for the answer. But the question is, can I use *ngIf context === *object*. will the condition context === *object* work? for example   

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="abc; context: myContext></ng-container>

<ng-template #errorMessage let-error>
    <p>
        <span *ngIf="error.key === 'pattern' && context === myContext ">{{....}}</span>
      </p>
</ng-template>

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do will not work. This is all JavaScript after all, and `===` does not do deep object comparison. `===` will only evaluate the reference of an object, not the content of the object itself.
You could do something like `context === object.name` if you wanted.

Personally, I wouldn't put all of this logic in the template for error messages. If you are going to go this route, you might want to look into [NgSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) instead of stringing all of these `ngIf`s together.